# How to remove black burn marks from burnt white plastic?

Tags: plastic, chemicals

A sheet of white hard plastic maybe 2 cms thick now has black burn marks on, and probably deep within it, from one of its edges being burnt off. Is there any chemical compound that will remove the black mark and restore the white color? Scrubbing Soap, cream lotion and toothpaste with warm water didn't work.

Comment: You can't "unburn" it. All you can do is remove that section, or paint over it, whichever is least ugly.

Comment: The suggestions so far of sanding, grinding, painting or cutting off the burnt part all seem to be unsatisfactory, so maybe if you [edit] to include a picture of said plastic and tell us what it came from, it would help spark the creative juices.

Comment: Burn marks are not a stain that can be cleaned.  For plastic about the only fix is to remove the burn areas, by sanding or cutting away.  If it is a block of plastic, then removing the burn marks should leave it a bit smaller, but looking like it should.

Comment: Sounds like you need to buy a new cutting board. What is this thing, what does it do, where is it, and is it removable? Take it to a somewhere with a table top belt sander large enough to do its largest edge and 'make it smaller' until the black parts are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting sheet like that means that the cut should have been positioned to leave some, or sufficient excess.

Now that edge needs planing or grinding or routing to the final dimension.

Comment: besides cutting. just want to remove the black burn marks

Comment: @user610620 Then sanding comes to mind.